# Type 'SimpleSpanProcessor' is not assignable to type 'SpanProcessor'. Type 'SimpleSpanProcessor' is not assignable to type 'SpanProcessor'

Tags: nestjs, open-telemetry

I am facing an error while creating tacing.ts file

```
import {
  BatchSpanProcessor,
  SimpleSpanProcessor,
} from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';
import { api, NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import * as process from 'process';
import { HttpInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http';
import { ExpressInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express';
import { NestInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-nestjs-core';
import { JaegerExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { B3Propagator } from '@opentelemetry/propagator-b3';

dotenv.config();

const jaegerExporter = new JaegerExporter({
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:14268/api/traces',
});


const traceExporter =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === `development` ? jaegerExporter : oltpExporter;

const spanProcessor =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`
    ? new SimpleSpanProcessor(traceExporter)
    : new BatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter);


export const otelSDK = new NodeSDK({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: `nestjs-otel`,
  }),
  spanProcessor,
  instrumentations: [
    new HttpInstrumentation(),
    new ExpressInstrumentation(),
    new NestInstrumentation(),
  ],
});
```

// gracefully shut down the SDK on process exit
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
otelSDK
.shutdown()
.then(
() => console.log('SDK shut down successfully'),
(err) => console.log('Error shutting down SDK', err),
)
.finally(() => process.exit(0));
});

package.json

```
    "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.36.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger": "^1.9.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto": "^0.35.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express": "^0.32.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http": "^0.35.0",
    "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-nestjs-core": "^0.32.0",
    "@opentelemetry/propagator-b3": "^1.9.0",
    "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.9.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.35.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.9.0",
    "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.9.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import BatchSpanProcessor from the `@opentelemetry/sdk-node` package itself to get a compatible version. e.g `import { api, NodeSDK, BatchSpanProcessor, SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';`